# Processing - logo banner not loading on website

Tags: visual-studio-code, processing, processing.js

I saved the processing code into visual studio code as a plain text file, i added the images/gradient.jpg as well as for the logo. I replaced the img code to canvas code and yet no animated logo appears. I have tried everything up to this point and nothing has worked. The logo is just not appearing.

```
@pjs preload="gradient.jpg,BRICKSxMORTAR_logo_transparentX.png";


PImage gradient;
PImage logo;




void setup(){
 size(792, 150);
 background(0);
 gradient = loadImage("gradient.jpg");
 logo = loadImage("BRICKSxMORTAR_logo_transparentX.png");
 }

void draw(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  float x = random(width);
  //ellipse(x, 20, 300, 200);
  image(gradient,300,11);
  ellipse(x, 200, x, 300);
  image(logo,1,9);
  //ellipse(x, x, 30, 20);{




 }
}


    <canvas id="logo" data-processing-sources="BxM_animatedLogo.pde"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen someone else with screenshots of code?  Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Comment: Please remember that Processing.js is no longer a real project, and hasn't been for a _long_ time now: I archived it back in December 2018. Don't use it for any kind of new project, and really: don't even keep using it for any older project that's only a few hundred lines: just rewrite it to [p5js](https://p5js.org/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to conver a sketch from processing-java to [processingjs](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js) (which is deprecated).

Using the WayBackMachine here is the [ProcessingJS `loadImage()` reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20120703145629/http://processingjs.org/reference/loadImage_/). Just in case, here's the description:

> Loads an image into a variable of type **PImage**. Four types of images (
> **.gif, .jpg, .tga, .png**) images may be loaded. To load correctly,
> <strike>images must be located in the data directory of the current sketch</strike>,
> *the images must be preloaded using @pjs preload specifying the path to
> the image.* In most cases, load all images in **setup()** to preload them
> at the start of the program. Loading images inside **draw()** will reduce
> the speed of a program. You can also load images from a data URI, such
> as "data:image/jpg;base64,{base 64 encoded data block}" which does not
> require any preloading.
>
> The filename parameter can also be a URL to a file found online. For
> security reasons, a Processing sketch found online can only download
> files from the same server from which it came.
>
> The extension of the filename parameter is used to determine the image
> type. In cases where the image filename does not end with a proper
> extension, specify the extension as the second parameter to
> loadImage(), as shown in the third example on this page.
>
> If an image is not loaded successfully, the **null** value is returned and
> an error message will be printed to the console. The error message
> does not halt the program, however the null value may cause a
> NullPointerException if your code does not check whether the value
> returned from loadImage() is null.
>
> **NOTE**: Some browers will not allow you to load images from file://
> URIs. It is recommended that you use a webserver for your development
> and testing to avoid any problems with file:// URIs.

I've emphasised the important part in italics and here's one the example snippets:

```
// @pjs preload must be used to preload the image

/* @pjs preload="laDefense.jpg"; */

PImage b;

void setup() {

  b = loadImage("laDefense.jpg");

  noLoop();

}



void draw() {

  image(b, 0, 0);

}
```

Hopefully, in your case it would be a matter of adding the `@pjs preload` comment:

```
/* @pjs preload="gradient.jpg,BRICKSxMORTAR_logo_transparentX.png"; */

PImage gradient;
PImage logo;

void setup() {
  size(792, 150);
  background(0);
  gradient = loadImage("gradient.jpg");
  logo = loadImage("BRICKSxMORTAR_logo_transparentX.png");
}

void draw() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    float x = random(width);
    image(gradient, 300, 11);
    ellipse(x, 200, x, 300);
    image(logo, 9, 11);
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but hopefully it works. The [source code indicates](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js/blob/1c1d58d7dfddfdbdc351e0160496078598a0b943/src/Parser/Parser.js#L1699) it should handle multiple images.

As a side note, in the future please post code snippets as formatted text. For HTML/CSS in some cases you can uses stackoverflow's code JS/HTML/CSS snippet feature or if it's simpler/more flexible use one of the many online services such as [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [codepen](https://codepen.io/), [glitch](https://glitch.com/). [Sketchpad.cc](http://sketchpad.cc/) might also work.
Images will take longer to load (and may even cost more money on a mobile device with a data plan) while text is lighter and easier to run/test. Overall it will make it much easier for others to support you.